# Restored Volume Group but No LV inside

Tags: rhel, lvm, restore

I created Volume group on 2TB ISCSI Block device . And on that I created Volume group and added the entry in fstab with options _netdev. But after reboot it didn't come online.

## What happened and what actions I took

1. Iscsi initiator didn't log in, so I had to manually login to target using iscsiadm utlity, and then storage appeared in /dev/disk/by-path and in fdisk
2. When used fdisk /dev/sdc it showed Partition type was back to gpt not LVMso I had to reset it to "8e" LVM.
3. When used fdisk /dev/sdc it showed Partition type was back to gpt not LVMso I had to reset it to "8e" LVM.
4. Looked for pv uuid in /etc/lvm/backup/vg_bacula_backups and created PV using

   ```
   # pvcreate --uuid WGCG9m-tl2b-840R-wSFS-w1oI-C1Pw-bcTTl4 --restorefile \
     /etc/lvm/archive/vg_bacula_backups_00000-6260716.vg /dev/sdc1
   ```

And pv was successfully created using old uuid and it appeared in pvscan

5. Restore Volume Group using

   ```
   # vgcfgrestore -f /etc/lvm/archive/vg_bacula_backups_00001-1157414378.vg vg_bacula_backups
   ```
6. Now when I tried to activate the VG using `vgdisplay -ay vg_bacula_backups`. It says

> 0 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg_bacula_backups" now active

Now what do I have to do to bring back the LV keeping the data intact ???

## fdisk -l output

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdc: 2199.0 GB, 2199023255552 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 267349 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 16384 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 16384 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1      267350  2147483647+  8e  Linux LVM
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

## parted output

```
Model: FreeBSD iSCSI Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 2199GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/16384B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  2199GB  2199GB               primary  lvm
```

Comment: That sounds like you used an old version of `fdisk` that hadn't been GPT aware, on a disk that used GPT partition table. And then did all the wrong things... please show both `fdisk -l` and `parted -l` for this disk.

Comment: ok one thing , Now this time i just run "# vgcfgrestore  vg_bacula_backups " without pointing it to /etc/lvm/archive and run vgchange -ay VG. it activated the volume. But when i tried to mount using  "mount -t ext4 /dev/vg_bacula_backups/bacula /SysBackups" , it slapped me with this error "mount: you must specify the filesystem type"

Comment: And another thing there are multiple entries of vg_bacula_backups like "vg_bacula_backups_00000-6260716.vg  vg_bacula_backups_00001-1157414378.vg  vg_bacula_backups_00002-1768584833.vg  vg_bacula_backups_00003-970443479.vg" what are these ???

Comment: And what's `cat /sys/block/sdc/sdc1/start`? (It should be `2048`.) As for your VG backup files, try `vgcfgrestore --list VG` it should show a description for each file, that should help you pick the right one (but don't restore until you know you actually need to).

Comment: For "cat /sys/block/sdc/sdc1/start" output is *1*. And for vgcfgrestore --list VG output is *No archives found in /etc/lvm/archive*

Comment: Then you should first fix your partition table (`parted /dev/sdc`, `mklabel gpt`, `mkpart primary 1MiB -1s`) before doing anything else... and maybe that alone will recover your LVM. If not you have to find the archive/backup file that actually has your logical volumes in them. These are text files you can read with `less`, see creation date, description, and actual data.